# WPF C# Application Idle Timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, devexpress

I've been searching and I found a lot of very good articles on timers.

This article [Monitor the idle time between user and application](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Monitorare-il-tempo-di-bba0178c) is the best one yet, but I have some issues with the results in this code.

The problem is, this is the idle time between the user and OS (not the application). When I move the mouse on the screen, it resets the timer.

I need to track idle time when the mouse isn't moving inside the application. If the user is off doing "whatever" in the OS, the timer is running.

Does anyone have any suggestions or articles on tracking the idle time of the application and user actions?

What i have so far

```
int totaltime = 0;

LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInf = new LASTINPUTINFO();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int cbSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int dwTime;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dt.Start();
}

public void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayTime();
}

public int GetLastInputTime()
{
    int idletime = 0;
    idletime = 0;
    lastInputInf.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInf);
    lastInputInf.dwTime = 0;

    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInf))
    {
        idletime = Environment.TickCount - lastInputInf.dwTime;
    }

    if (idletime != 0)
    {
        return idletime / 1000;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

private void DisplayTime()
{
    totaltime = GetLastInputTime();
    if (GetLastInputTime().Equals(1))
    {
        Label1.Content = "Tempo di inattività pari a" + " " + GetLastInputTime().ToString() + " " + "secondo";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Content = "Tempo di inattività pari a" + " " + GetLastInputTime().ToString() + " " + "secondi";
    }
}

private void Window_MouseMove(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (totaltime > 5)
    {
        FrmLogin log = new FrmLogin();
        log.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note, this code is in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

Comment: I wouldn't start a timer unless you need something to happen after a certain amount of time.  If you do then ok but if you just want to know the time the user was away then track the time the user is in the application by updating a variable with the DateTime.Now value and then when they leave / return grab the difference in the saved time and the current time value.

Comment: @RazorSharp: Did you try to handle the window's PreviewMouseMove event?

Comment: @Michael Puckett II No, actually I did not. I just played with Mouse Move. Let me try Preview and see what comes from it. Thank you

Comment: @Michael Puckett II: No joy. I tried DXWindow_PreviewMouseMove, DXWindow_LostFocus and DXWindow_MouseLeave... None of them work. All I want is the timer to run when the app has lost focus...

Comment: If you just want to know if the application has focus or not you can start the timer / stop it in the App.xaml file.  There are two events that handle it "Activated" and "Deactivated".  Those events will trigger whenever the app has or loses focus.  However; this does not trigger just because the mouse leaves but only when the mouse clicks the desktop or another app giving it the focus and then again when the app is clicked back on.  This can be via several events, mouse click on window, taskbar, scroll wheel, alt + tab to app, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so in WPF here's an option.  You an still use the Mouse enter and leave if you prefer but this works great. I made a simple app just to show. Here are the files.  When the application loses focus the timer starts in milliseconds and when you return it stops.  You can see how much time you were away from the app.  Modify as needed; this is just for show and logic.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="TimingLostFocus.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
             Activated="Application_Activated" 
             Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;

namespace TimingLostFocus
{
    public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private long millisecondsWithoutFocus;
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs eventArgs) => Timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => MillisecondsWithoutFocus++;
        private void Application_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) => Timer.Stop();
        private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e) =>Timer.Start();
        public Timer Timer { get; set; } = new Timer(100);

        public long MillisecondsWithoutFocus
        {
            get => millisecondsWithoutFocus;
            set
            {
                millisecondsWithoutFocus = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MillisecondsWithoutFocus)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindow" x:Class="TimingLostFocus.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Milliseconds Without Focus" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="millisecondsWithoutFocusTextBlock" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace TimingLostFocus
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static int WindowsCount = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (Application.Current is App app)
            {
                app.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(App.MillisecondsWithoutFocus))
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => millisecondsWithoutFocusTextBlock.Text = app.MillisecondsWithoutFocus.ToString()));
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```